# Migrate entity framework core db first sql server to oracle

Tags: oracle, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a .net core project where i am using entity framework db first connecting to sql server which is working fine, now i have similar set of tables in oracle can i just run the project by changing connection string and provider to oracle? Or any major rework is needed to make this work?

Comment: Maybe. It depends. How "similar" is "similar"? If the names are identical, if there are no implementation-specific types, you may only have to change the connection string. Have you tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to regenerate the DbContext mappings using reverse engineering

Comment: If the names are identical and the mappings have no SQL Server-specific types or defaults, reverse engineering probably isn't needed

Comment: Thanks, may be in my case its needed but i get it what u mean.